# Is there a word that describes the sound you make when you chuckle/breathe/cough in agreement with something?

Tags: writing, sounds

I am writing a novel and am constantly trying to figure out how to describe the action when someone gives a sort of small cough or a quick "huh" in agreement. I suppose it would be the non-word equivalent of "I'll say" or "You think?" 
To be specific, I'll use it in a dialogue.

"He must really hate Ian, then."

Clarissa [insert word here]. "Yes."

It's usually used when the speaker is trying to convey that the subject is much more serious than their conversation partner is taking it.

Answer (score 2):

**Breath**

It's called a *sigh*. Depending on the gravity of the context, an adverb may be used to add depth to the sigh, viz

> > "He must really hate Ian, then."
> >
> > Clarissa *sighed* [resignedly]. "Yes."

**Chuckle**

In your use case, you're thinking of a *snigger*.

> > "He must really hate Ian, then."
> >
> > Clarissa *sniggered*. "Yes."

Chuckle, as you already have it, should also suffice

**Cough**

The closest I can think of in this context is a *grunt*. I can't think of a situation where a cough is used as a sign of affirmation, unless the more recent sarcastic cough where a speaker makes a statement and someone (or the same speaker) coughs out a name as a snide affirmation, e.g.

> > Dorian: Some people just don't have boundaries
> >
> > Oscar : ** cough ** Ian ** cough **

EDIT: A *scoff* might work here. It sounds like coughing somewhat, but it's usually applied in contempt, rather than resignation or despair (as I presume you're trying to portray)